# Why isn't celery periodic task working?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to create a periodic task within a Django app.

I added this to my `settings.py`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'get_checkins': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.get_checkins',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
    }
}
```

I'm just getting started with Celery and haven't figured out which broker I want to use, so I added this as well to just bypass the broker for the time being:

```
if DEBUG:
    CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

I also created a `celery.py` file in my project folder:

```
from  __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'testproject.settings')
app = Celery('testproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Inside my app, called `api`, I made a `tasks.py` file:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def get_checkins():
    print('hello from get checkins')
```

I'm running the worker and beat with `celery -A testproject worker --beat -l info`

It starts up fine and I can see the task is registered under `[tasks]`, but I don't see any jobs getting logged. Should be one per second. Can anyone tell why this isn't executing?

Comment: Have you tried just `'schedule': 1.0`?

Comment: That works as well, but hasn't fixed the problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your post and don't see any comment on the broker you are using along with celery. 
Have you installed a broker like Rabbitmq? Is it running or logging some kind of error?
Celery needs a broker to send and receive data.

Check the documentation here (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#choosing-a-broker)

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm not using a broker at the moment. I'm just running things synchronously with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`. Obviously I'll use one in production, though.

Comment: Ok so is not a broker issue. Although I strongly recommend you testing with one before deploying in production. Is celery logging any error or message?